# Android Download file- Jackson readvalue failing to load the java class - heap size error

Tags: android, file, download

I am trying to download an apk file  through a rest service via http GET. The format recieved is JSON. I am able to recieve the data but it fails while deserializing to a java object. I get Outofmemory error.

I am running the file download process in an Asyn Task. Is there other better options to achieve the same functionality. The apk is about 2 MB. The data from a wcf service is Base64 encoded in json

```
private  class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) 
    {
        try
        {
             URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]); 
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
              c.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
              c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
              c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
              c.setRequestProperty("Device","13");
              c.setRequestProperty("Authorization","toughsecurity");
              c.setDoInput(true); 
              c.connect();                    
              String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"; 
              File file = new File(PATH); 
              file.mkdirs(); 
              File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk"); 
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);                    
             if(c.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
          {

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+"temp.txt");

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = c.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                out.flush();
                out.close(); 

                InputStream in=new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+"temp.txt");


               ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

              AppDownload download= mapper.readValue(in, AppDownload.class);

                 byte[] data1=Base64Coder.decodeLines(download.Data);
                  byte[] content = data1;
                int size = content.length;
                InputStream is1 = null;
                byte[] b = new byte[size];           
                is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
                 int len1 = 0; 
                 while ((len1 = is1.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
                     fos.write(buffer, 0, len1); 
                 } 
                 fos.close(); 




          }


             c.disconnect(); 


        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Jackson error",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      //  mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
       // mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't be surprised if the JSON library is barfing on a 2MB JSON file.

i know it probably isn't an option to change the API, but it's pretty strange to be returning binary data in JSON. it's not made for that. the API should provide two endpoints ... one that gets the object meta data including a link to the content, and one that returns the content only in binary form.

you could also try another JSON library.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I am able to successfully download the file from an url directly but for security reasons we wanted to use a service, because we pass in a token in the headers. And as you said i could get the metadata from the service.